# Lowest price list price

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I created alternatyve_pricelist in SO. When a product is chosen I want to go through all price lists original and alternative and use the lowest price.

Example.
A client has a 20% discount, but on the day SO is made, the product category of a product he buys have a 30% discount. So pricelist with 30% has to be used.

I do struggle in this part as I don't know how can I compare all pricelist and chose the lowest price. Need to some help here.

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

alternative_pricelist_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'product.pricelist', string='Alternative Pricelists')

 @api.onchange('amount_total')
    def check_pricelist_low_price(self):
            for order in self:
                for line in order.order_line:
                    product_pricelist_item = self.env['product.pricelist.item'].search([('product_tmpl_id', '=', line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.id)])
                         ????????
```